# Editing rows in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to update a datatable row  with PrimeFaces 3.1.1 but it makes all values null.

```
 public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    Client us= (Client) event.getObject();
    System.out.println("event edit"+us);
    clientService.editClient( us );

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Client modifié", ((Client) event.getObject()).getName_customer());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

This is my page xhtml:

```
 <h:form>
 <p:dataTable var="client" value="#{clientBean.clients}" widgetVar="clientTable" emptyMessage="No customers found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{clientBean.filteredClients}" paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"  editable="true" id="testContainer">
 <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{clientBean.onRowEdit(event)}"  />
 <f:facet name="header"><p:outputPanel><h:outputText value="Recherche d'un client:" /> </p:outputPanel>
 </f:facet>
 <p:column filterBy="#{client.user.username}" headerText="Collaborateur"  filterMatchMode="contains">
 <h:outputText value="#{client.user.username}" />
  </p:column>
 <p:column filterBy="#{client.name_customer}" headerText="Nom"  filterMatchMode="contains">
  <f:facet name="output">
<h:link outcome="CustomerDetails?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"  value="#{client.name_customer}"  >
<f:param  name="idCustomer" value="#{client.costumer_id}"></f:param>
 <f:param  name="nameCustomer" value="#{client.name_customer}"></f:param>
</h:link> </f:facet>
<f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{client.name_customer}"/></f:facet>
</p:cellEditor> 
</p:column>
<p:column filterBy="#{client.statut}" headerText="Statut"  filterMatchMode="contains">
```

Comment: Is this listener method invoked by the `rowEdit` event? How do you invoke the `rowEdit` event in `<p:dataTable>`?

Comment: <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{clientBean.onRowEdit}"  />

Comment: Do you really have the property `name_customer` in your `Client` model? The name does not follow the general naming convention. It should look something like `nameCustomer` (it should not be a probelm though).

Comment: yes I have the property name_customer in my model and it is no problem in the case of adding a Client

Comment: Is the Client object the field being modified or does it represent a row in your datatable? If it represents a row you might want to look into RowEditEvent.getObject().getSoure()

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your object Client **us** is null , try to display a property from your object **us** if is null so that will confirm that you don't get your object from your page correctly . So i suggest you to replace that :

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{clientBean.onRowEdit}" />
```

with that

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{clientBean.onRowEdit(event)}" />
```

Note that i just added the event property to onRowEdit.

Comment: when i add   event property to onRowEdit, i have this exception:                                                                 javax.el.ELException: /pages/newCostumer.xhtml @76,85 listener="#{clientBean.onRowEdit(event)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
 at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:42)

Comment: can you post your page xhtml ?